# how to loop through this array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to loop through this array:

```
$securePages=array("admin.php","addslot.php","classpost.php");

$pagename="admin.php"
```

Then if admin.php is found then execute this code:

```
header("location:index.php");
exit();
```

How would I put together this looping statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if (in_array("admin.php", $securePages)) {
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (in_array($pagename, $securePages)) {
    header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
    exit();    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am thinking this might do what you want to do...

```
$securePages = array("admin.php","addslot.php","classpost.php");
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = parse_url($url);
$path = $url['path']; // bar.php

if (in_array($path, $securePages)) {
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was aiming for, I'm now learning php thanks a lot for the helpful hints.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (in_array($pagename,$securePages)) {
  header("location:index.php");
 exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach($securePages AS $page)
  {
      if ($page == "admin.php")
      {
           header("location:index.php");
           exit();
      }
  }
```

Comment: I voted this up because it IS correct. However, it isn't the best way. See the others above.

Answer (score 1):

just in case you wanted to know how to actually loop through an array.

```
$securePages=array("admin.php","addslot.php","classpost.php");
foreach ($securePages as $value) {

  //$value is an item in the array.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and [if](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)